# Airflow DAG: ETL_toll_data.py does not exist in 'dag' table

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-2.x, airflow-webserver

I tried to unpause an airflow dag with the python file "**ETL_toll_data.py**" that I created in one of my projects, but I got the error "***DAG: ETL_toll_data does not exist in 'dag' table***"

I used the airflow command "***$ airflow dags unpause ETL_toll_data***"
This was on an ubuntu OS on a virtual machine.
I successfully submitted the python file by copying it into the dag folder in the $AIRFLOW_HOME directory.
I can see the dag as part of the dag list when I run the command "*airflow dags list*"

The "unpause" command is expected to change the pause status of the dag in the image below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9iEb.png)

I need help with what to do here to enable me unpause the dag from the cli.
I can do this from the frontend by simple clicking the toggle button, but I want to be able to manage the dags from cli.